# PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError vs runZonedGuarded

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone explain(or provide a link to explaining documentation) when i must use PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError and when runZonedGuarded? As I understand it, they are both about handling async exceptions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update (2023-07-04):**

Current version of very good cli(0.15.0 as of writing) is not using runZonedGuarded. I think both parties moved away from the mentioned function because of it's complicated usage or not being friendly with WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(). But both options are still working. So once again as stated in the original answer:

As always do your own research/testing and choose the option according to your needs.

**Original answer:**

I was searching an answer for the same question, and I think I've found a somewhat satisfying answer:

### Option #1 PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/onError.html

Example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter

```
Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
    };
    // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };
    runApp(MyApp());

}
```

But an important quote from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/instance.html

> Consider avoiding static references to this singleton though
> PlatformDispatcher.instance and instead prefer using a binding for
> dependency resolution such as
> WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.
>
> Static access of this object means that Flutter has few, if any
> options to fake or mock the given object in tests. Even in cases where
> Dart offers special language constructs to forcefully shadow such
> properties, those mechanisms would only be reasonable for tests and
> they would not be reasonable for a future of Flutter where we
> legitimately want to select an appropriate implementation at runtime.
>
> The only place that WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher is
> inappropriate is if access to these APIs is required before the
> binding is initialized by invoking runApp() or
> WidgetsFlutterBinding.instance.ensureInitialized(). In that case, it
> is necessary (though unfortunate) to use the
> PlatformDispatcher.instance object statically.

### Option #2 runZonedGuarded

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.7/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html

We also have another option as in your question which is used in very good cli.

```
Future<void> bootstrap(FutureOr<Widget> Function() builder) async {
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    log(details.exceptionAsString(), stackTrace: details.stack);
  };

  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();

  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async => runApp(await builder()),
    (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
  );
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if you use `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` outside of the `runZonedGuarded` method. So keep that in mind. Some issue links:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6964#issuecomment-915935180

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48972

### Conclusion

Since the docs state that `PlatformDispatcher.instance` usage as unfortunate, I guess we can conclude that using `runZonedGuarded` is the better option.

As always do your own research/testing and choose the option according to your needs.

Comment: The API documentation states you should preferably use `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher` instead of `PlatformDispatcher.instance` provided that you have previously invoked `runApp()` or `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`

Comment: Yes option #1 can't do that because the error binding is before the `runApp` call. But option #2 has problems on its own. So just pick one and stick to it until it becomes officially deprecated imo. I'm still using runZonedGuarded.

Answer (score 1):

I got a warning after upgrading to Flutter 3.10.5:

```
════════ Exception caught by Flutter framework ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during runApp:
Zone mismatch.

The Flutter bindings were initialized in a different zone than is now being used. This will likely cause confusion and bugs as any zone-specific configuration will inconsistently use the configuration of the original binding initialization zone or this zone based on hard-to-predict factors such as which zone was active when a particular callback was set.
It is important to use the same zone when calling `ensureInitialized` on the binding as when calling `runApp` later.
To make this warning fatal, set BindingBase.debugZoneErrorsAreFatal to true before the bindings are initialized (i.e. as the first statement in `void main() { }`).
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      BindingBase.debugCheckZone.<anonymous closure>
binding.dart:497
#1      BindingBase.debugCheckZone
binding.dart:502
#2      runApp
binding.dart:1080
#3      main.<anonymous closure>
main.dart:52
#4      FirebaseDiagnosticsService.initCrashlytics.<anonymous closure>
firebase_diagnostics_service.dart:53
<asynchronous suspension>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I was using `runZonedGuarded`. So I did some research. It turns out that using `runZonedGuarded` for Crashlytics is deprecated. You can see that in this commit where all references to `runZonedGuarded` were replaced:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/commit/8a0caa05d5abf6fef5bf0e654654dcd0b6ec874a

Also note that the current official documentation doesn't mention `runZonedGuarded` anymore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter

The recommended way is this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
    };
    // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };
    runApp(MyApp());

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: After earning my first downvote, now I get why people complain about it all the time. At least this answer has good intentions even though it is flawed. First of all OP doesn't mention Firebase or Crashlytics. Also Firebase doesn't contain official dart or flutter docs. Having said that I also found out that very good cli has removed runZonedGuarded from their code. So I'm going to edit my answer and include these developments. But I think runZonedGuarded is still an option, and it's not deprecated from dart or flutter.

Comment: Hey @Umut, thanks for your reply. Downvoting is a part of StackOverflow. Sometimes an answer was good at the time of writing, but then becomes outdated and is not the best solution to the problem anymore. I've had answers downvoted many times. It's OK :) As to Firebase: It does have official Flutter/Dart docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter You are correct that runZonedGuarded is not marked as deprecated, but it seems that popular projects have replaced its use with that of PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError. Have a great day!

Comment: Also thank you for the explanation. I still think your answer is not better because it doesn't explain the differences. It only shows a specific use case, and wrongfully claims a deprecation status. Also what I meant is official status of a function being deprecated or not doesn't live in the Firebase site. It's at flutter.dev or dart.dev as of writing. But I think we agree on deprecation status and popular projects not using the said function anymore so no further discussions are needed here.